# Facebook Login callback not called and popup won't close in IE10 on Win8

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

For my Facebook-Application the Facebook.login Dialog does not close after logging into facebook and granting the permissions. I tried a workaround with an interval and FB.getLoginStatus but this response only returns "not_authorized" even if i had granted the permissions and the app appears in my account-settings.

I have the following Tags on my page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

[the meta tag not seems to be the problem as described in an similar question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11529942/facebook-login-popup-wont-close-in-ie10-on-windows-8)

```
FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
        status: false,
        channelUrl: 'My_Channel_File.html'
    });
```

The channel-File contains the same script-tag as above.
the other parameters i varied alot: oauth, xfbml, cookie, status and frictionlessRequests(i've seen somewhere else)

this problem only occurs on Win8 with IE10

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I solved the problem. You need to init the FB-jssdk asynchronously:</strike>

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });
};

(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

when you do it like this for whatever reason the Dialog of the FB.login closes as expected end everything works fine =)

**Edit:**
The problem was a security-property that has to be changed in the IE:
Internet-properties -> Safety -> the check-box on the bottom "Secure Mode" has to be enabled then it will work with a synchronous as well as an asynchronous FB.init
(I'm German so I don't know the English property-names sry for that)